# Bring up vagrant boxes simultaneously

Tags: vagrant

Vagrant brings up one box at a time. Is there a way to make vagrant bring up all boxes at the same time?

The Vagrantfile configuration which I'm using for several boxes has the following format:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.define :master do |master|
    # Master config...
  end

  config.vm.define :slave1 do |slave|
    # Slave config...
  end
end
```

Now, when running *> vagrant up* Vagrant will start by setting up master and once that is done it will set up slave1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your provider, you can pass pass the --parallel flag to vagrant up.

`vagrant up --parallel`
 

As of March 17th, Mitchell Hashimoto noted that Virtualbox is not a provider that supports parallelism. [Reference](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/T1XSQDK7e7c)